# how to make list comprehension using while in loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, list-comprehension

I have such loop:

```
ex = [{u'white': []},
 {u'yellow': [u'9241.jpg', []]},
  {u'red': [u'241.jpg', []]},
   {u'blue': [u'59241.jpg', []]}]


for i in ex:
    while not len(i.values()[0]):
        break
    else:
        print i
        break
```

I need always to return first dict with lenght of values what is higher then 0
but i want to make it with list comprehension

Comment: List comprehension is used when you want to retrieve a list not a dict

Comment: Why? List comprehensions *create* lists; they are not simply an alternate form of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension would produce a whole list, while you want just *one item*.

Use a generator expression instead, and have the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) iterate to the first value:

```
next((i for i in ex if i.values()[0]), None)
```

I've given `next()` a default to return as well; if there is no matching dictionary, `None` is returned instead.

Demo:

```
>>> ex = [{u'white': []},
...  {u'yellow': [u'9241.jpg', []]},
...   {u'red': [u'241.jpg', []]},
...    {u'blue': [u'59241.jpg', []]}]
>>> next((i for i in ex if i.values()[0]), None)
{u'yellow': [u'9241.jpg', []]}
```

You should, however, rethink your data structure. Dictionaries with just one key-value pair suggest to me you wanted a different type instead; tuples perhaps:

```
ex = [
    (u'white', []),
    (u'yellow', [u'9241.jpg', []]),
    (u'red', [u'241.jpg', []]),
    (u'blue', [u'59241.jpg', []]),
]
```